# nftables: Possible to block SYN packets with payload?

Tags: firewall, linux-networking, tcp, nftables

Is it possible to drop all TCP SYN packets with a payload using `nftables`?

The man pages mention various `length` options, but none that I could get to work for TCP packets without syntax errors.

I am using kernel v6.2.10, and nftables v1.0.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today a *direct* feature for this doesn't exist with *nftables*. *nftables*' raw payload feature is too limited for this. A TCP segment has no direct header information for the data length. It has its header length as `@th,96,4 << 2` and that's not useful to reach the data part. *iptables*' [`u32`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#u32) match can do better but still not enough: it can chain computations and get a pointer to the start of the TCP data payload and match their content (ok *nftables*' very recent `@ih` might perhaps do the same). Still, since it can't do subtractions either nor is flexible enough, it can't be used to compute the data payload length but might perhaps have been good enough ("Any  access  of memory outside [skb->data,skb->end] causes the match to fail.": for data size between 1 and 3, behavior might be undefined).

For what it's worth, *tcpdump*'s BPF [can do such computation for IPv4](https://superuser.com/questions/1550217/filter-tcp-packet-payload-length-in-tcpdump) because it knowns how to do subtractions:

```
tcpdump 'ip and (tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn|tcp-rst|tcp-ack|tcp-fin) == tcp-syn) and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) > 0)'
```

---

### Using a lookup table for the IPv4 case

What can't be calculated at runtime can sometimes be pre-calculated and put in a lookup table instead. For IPv4 and *nftables*, one can build a lookup table with all valid values for the triplet (IP [Total Length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol_version_4#Total_Length), [IHL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol_version_4#IHL), [Data Offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure)) where the TCP data size would be zero, and match (or fail to match) this lookup table.

- possible IP header size in 4-bytes words ([IHL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol_version_4#IHL)): between 5 and 15.
- possible TCP header size in 4-bytes words ([Data Offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure)): between 5 and 15 too.

11x11=121 possibilities where IP length ([Total Length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol_version_4#Total_Length)) = IHLx4 + DOx4

Note: with IPv6 and its variable number of extra headers between the fixed header and the final protocol (TCP) header, such method can't be used because the lookup table(s) would probably have a very huge size instead of just 121 elements.

`tcpsynzero.nft`:

```
table ip tcpsynzero # for idempotence
delete table ip tcpsynzero # for idempotence

table ip tcpsynzero {
    flags dormant

    set validtriplet {
        typeof ip length . @nh,4,4 . @th,96,4;
    }

    chain dropsynwithdata {
        tcp flags syn ip length . @nh,4,4 . @th,96,4 != @validtriplet counter drop
    }

    chain prerouting {
        type filter hook prerouting priority 0; policy accept;
        goto dropsynwithdata
    }

    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
        goto dropsynwithdata
    }
}
```

Load first with `nft -f tcpsynzero.nft` (table is loaded but *dormant* thus not enabled, because without the loaded set it would drop all SYNs).

Bash script `generatetriplets.bash` to generate *nftables* commands to populate the set:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for ihl in {5..15}; do
    for _do in {5..15}; do
        l=$((ihl*4+_do*4))
        printf 'add element ip tcpsynzero validtriplet { %d . %#x . %#x }\n' $l $ihl $_do
    done
done
```

Populate set with:

```
bash generatetriplets.bash | nft -f -
```

Finally enable the table (redeclaring the table is almost a no-op, except it removes the *dormant* flag):

```
nft add table ip tcpsynzero
```

---

### Test

tested on Linux 6.1.x and nftables 1.0.7, and by (ab)using [TCP Fast Open](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v6.1#n814) with a few forced modes:

- Linux server at 192.0.2.2 where the *nftables* ruleset was installed.

  ```
  sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_fastopen=0x602
  ```

  and

  ```
  socat tcp4-listen:8080,reuseaddr,fork -
  ```
- Linux client with

  ```
  sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_fastopen=0x5
  ```

  and

  - working immediately:

    ```
    curl http://192.0.2.2:8080/
    ```
  - 1st SYN blocked (and retried with normal SYN after 1s):

    ```
    curl --tcp-fastopen http://192.0.2.2:8080/
    ```

    Note: testing with the *nftables* ruleset on the client rather than on the server has no delay because the output verdict of *drop* triggers an immediate error on the socket but this is immediately retried by the kernel with a normal SYN. The counter in the drop rule is of course still incremented since a packet was still dropped.

---

Similar workaround used in an other *nftables* case: [Nftables timestamp map](https://serverfault.com/questions/996037/nftables-timestamp-map)

Comment: Wow, much appreciate the effort and detailed answer! Thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 0):

What about dropping by tcp option?

For example to drop outbound TCP SYN with TCP Fast Open Cookie:

iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT -p tcp --syn --tcp-option 34 -j DROP

(which AFAICT effectively forces fall back to non tcp fast open mode and thus payload less)